# How to make two small changes to a contourplot produced in lattice

Tags: r, contour, lattice

I would like to make two cosmetic changes to a contourplot using the lattice function. These are

1. to expand the size of the panel titles;
2. add a title to the legend and key section, and shrink the colorkey object to fit this.

A graphic showing what I mean is below, as on this occasion it will likely be more informative than the code.

[image: example plot]

Solutions to either or both problems much appreciated.

Comment: panel titles: `par.strip.text=list(cex=1.2)`

Comment: legend title: `legend=list(top=list(fun=grid::textGrob("Key", y=0, x=1.09)))` (you have to adjust the parameters `x` and `y`)