# How to add a title to the color key on a contourplot?

Tags: r, lattice

How does one add a title to the color key in a lattice contourplot?

```
library(lattice)
contourplot(volcano, region=T, main='title')
```

[image]

I've searched the documentation and don't see anything about text or titles for the `colorkey` argument or in any of the other contourplot/levelplot options.

Comment: @user20650: Thanks for the links.  I posted an answer including the less complicated of the two.

Comment: you're answer is much better - learned something new

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a few different ways to do this and thought I'd post them for posterity:

#### Option 1

Sourced from a comment: [How to make two small changes to a contourplot produced in lattice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25400734/how-to-make-two-small-changes-to-a-contourplot-produced-in-lattice) thanks to @rcs.

```
contourplot(volcano, region=T, main='title', subtitle='sub',
    legend=list(top=list(fun=grid::textGrob("Volcanoes", y=0, x=1.09))))
```

#### Option 2

Sourced from: [How to add a title to legend scale using levelplot in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528527/how-to-add-a-title-to-legend-scale-using-levelplot-in-r)  thanks to @user20650.

```
contourplot(volcano, region=T,main='title') 
trellis.focus("legend", side="right", clipp.off=TRUE, highlight=FALSE)
grid.text('Volcanoes', 0.5, 1.07, hjust=0.5, vjust=1)
trellis.unfocus()
```

[image]

Comment: Just for the record (and very similar to **Option 2**): `library(grid); downViewport("plot_01.legend.right.vp");
grid.text('Volcanoes', 0.5, 1.07, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 1)` works as well!